# Raycasting in Unity 2D c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, raycasting

I'm new to c# and trying to figure out how to get raycasting to work here in Unity3d's new 2d support.

I'm getting the error "cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Ray2D' to 'UnityEngine.Vector2'"

```
for (int i = 0; i<3; i ++) {
        float dir = Mathf.Sign(deltaY);
        float x = (p.x + c.x - s.x/2) + s.x/2 * i;
        float y = p.y + c.y + s.y/2 * dir;

        ray = new Ray2D(new Vector3(x, y), new Vector3(0, dir));
        Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction);
        hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Abs(deltaY), collisionMask);

        if (hit != null && hit.collider != null)
        {
        }
        if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray,out hit,Mathf.Abs(deltaY),collisionMask)) {
            float dst = Vector2.Distance (ray.origin, hit.point);

            if (dst > skin) {
                deltaY = dst * dir + skin;
            }
            else {
                deltaY = 0;
            }

            grounded = true;

            break;

        }
    }
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: if (Physics2D.Raycast(ray,out hit,Mathf.Abs(deltaY),collisionMask))

Answer (score 4):

See the [`Physics2D.Raycast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html) documentation, the method is defined as

```
static RaycastHit2D Raycast(Vector2 origin, Vector2 direction, float distance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity);
```

With the parameters defined as

> origin:            The point in 2D space where the ray originates.
>
> direction: Vector representing the direction of the ray.
>
> distance:  Maximum distance over which to cast the ray.
>
> layerMask: Filter to detect Colliders only on certain layers.
>
> minDepth:  Only include objects with a Z coordinate (depth) greater than this value.
>
> maxDepth:  Only include objects with a Z coordinate (depth) less than this value.

You are using a `Ray2D` instead of a `Vector2D` for `origin`. If you simply replace `ray` with a `Vector2D` it will work

```
Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector2(x, y),out hit,Mathf.Abs(deltaY),collisionMask)
```

For more information, see [passing parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. Do call like you did in code earlier:

   hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, Mathf.Abs(deltaY), collisionMask);
2. This code is useless:

   if (hit != null && hit.collider != null)
       {
       }

But if you need to enter some logics in brackets - you don't need to check hit for null - it is always an object, just check hit.collider